# Calling a nested function with onclick()

Tags: javascript

I have two buttons: `<button onclick="check()">Check</button>` and `<button onclick="newGame()">New</button>`.  I want to run the **check** function only after the **New** button has been clicked, so I am nesting it inside the **newGame** function.

My question is, how can I call the **check** function when I click the corresponding button? I do not want to execute it in one continuous flow.

Answer (score 1):

Disable the 'Check' button by default.  When the 'New' button has been clicked, within the event handler, enable the 'Check' button.

```
<button id="chkBtn" onclick="check()" disabled>Check</button>
<button onclick="newGame()">New</button>

function newGame()
{
  // on success
  document.getElementById('chkBtn').disabled = false;  
  // can't remember if it's enabled | disabled
}
```

Comment: please remove his inline event handlers (that is a clear anti pattern)